# How can I extend a Flex Panel to allow cornerRadius per corner?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

It looks like the "cornerRadius" property of a Panel only changes the top corners and bottom if using a ControlBar.  I'd like to specify a corner radius for each of the corners individual.

I know Degrafa can do this but I'd like to avoid if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a panel you'll need to set the `roundedBottomCorners` property to true.

If you need per corner radius you have the option of implementing your own skin using Degrafa or you simply use a mask to do so.